# Controlling Python script from PHP panel

Tags: php, python, web

I have a Python script that runs to parsing data and do some functions, my script work done.
I plan to show status and output of my script on web-based panel, "PHP panel".

What is the best approach to do that and get sync data between my script and the panel?  Also for controlling my script (start, stop, send parameters,...)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a [system call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).  The return_val will provide you with your output.  You will also need to use escapeshellarg on the arguments passed.